# setting and retrieving data from session

Tags: jsf

My bean is request scoped. I am setting a data object in session using below code:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("loggedInUser", loggedInUser);
```

I am trying to retrieve data in view using below line:

```
#{sessionScope["loggedInUser"].firstName}
```

But data in view comes out to be blank. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Use a `SessionScoped` bean to keep the values. Then access the bean from EL.

Comment: That can happen if 1) `loggedInUser` is `null`, or 2) `loggedInUser` has no `firstName` set, or 3) you're displaying it in a different session.  Have you already excluded those rather logical causes?

Comment: 1) loggedInUser is not null 2) It also has the firstName 3) I am setting it in sessionMap during login and displaying it on the the Welcome Page(opens on hitting login button), so session must also be the same.